# Getting "Process unexpectedly exit" while run the application and rebuild the app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am Using Windows 7 Operating system. I have installed Android studio in my system. While creating project, the project was created successfully, But while run the application getting **Process unexpectedly exit.** and even rebuild the project also getting same issue.

The following is the full error details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #9: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #8: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #10: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Again I have uninstalled the Android studio, Reinstall it, But again getting same issue.

Please help on this.

Thanks

Comment: I have same issue, need to install windows 10, check on this

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/android-studio-has-a-problem-and-needs-help/36645/3

Answer of : 27zarifboyevjavohir
Javohir Zarifoyev